# perl regex for replacing multiple matches with corresponding replacements

Tags: regex, perl

[image]

I'd like to replace each match like this:

```
fn.doc(
fn.collection(
fn.distinctValues(   # convert to camelcase also
```

I'm able to find the matches using regex but not sure how to do replacements
.Here's the regex `(\w+)(:)(\w+-\w+\()|(\w+)(:)(\w+\()` 
http://regex101.com/r/kD9zG8

**Expected Output:**

```
let $local-config := fn.doc($alert-action)/alert:action/alert:name
let $local-coll := fn.collection($uri)/alert:action/alert:name
let $global-coll := fn.distinctValues(fn.collection($global-uri)/alert:action/alert:name[../alert:name = 'ml_alert_action_17_01_action'])
```

Please help!

Comment: How about you also share that regex101 link and put the test string in your question? Also what replacement do you want?

Comment: @Hamza - added link. I've already mentioned in the question. In case its not clear, I'd like to replace `:` with `.` and hyphenated strings with camelCase but not any string, it must be function name not any other string

Comment: Is `fn:` a fixed string? You don't want it to replace `foo:` if it happens to appear in that spot? You have to be specific, down to the small details.

Comment: No. It can any word (ex: `fn, xdmp, admin` etc) and they should not be replaced

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following simple regex should work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = do {local $/; <DATA>};

$data =~ s/(\w+):(\w+)-?(\w*)\(/$1.$2\u$3(/g;

print $data;

__DATA__
let $local-config := fn:doc($alert-action)/alert:action/alert:name
let $local-coll := fn:collection($uri)/alert:action/alert:name
let $global-coll := fn:distinct-values(fn:collection($global-uri)/alert:action/alert:name[../alert:name = 'ml_alert_action_17_01_action'])
```

Outputs:

```
let $local-config := fn.doc($alert-action)/alert:action/alert:name
let $local-coll := fn.collection($uri)/alert:action/alert:name
let $global-coll := fn.distinctValues(fn.collection($global-uri)/alert:action/alert:name[../alert:name = 'ml_alert_action_17_01_action'])
```

#### Enhancement for 3+ words

To handle more than 2 words, you can change the regex to the following:

```
$data =~ s{(\w+):([\w-]+)(?=\()}{"$1.".lcfirst join '', map ucfirst, split /-/, $2}eg;
```

Or if your perl version supports the `/r` switch:

```
$data =~ s{(\w+):([\w-]+)(?=\()}{"$1.".$2=~s/-(.)/\u$1/gr}eg;
```

Comment: Thanks that works. I just remembered one more little thing. The function names can contain multiple words separated by `-`. Ex: `fn:myfunc-one(),fn:myfunc-one-two(), fn:myfunc-one-two-there()`. There is no  limit on this pattern. Would you please modify for that?

Comment: Nice replacement job, +1 :)

Comment: Bingo! Thats brilliant! Thanks a lot @Miller. Appreciate your help.